# Cannot create a file when using malloced char arrays

Tags: arrays, c, dynamic, malloc

I am coding a PE file viewer in standard C by following [this](https://www.ired.team/miscellaneous-reversing-forensics/windows-kernel-internals/pe-file-header-parser-in-c++) article. It is pretty neat, but I have a problem with the first lines:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Windows.h"
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    const int MAX_FILEPATH = 255;
    char fileName[MAX_FILEPATH] = {0};
    memcpy_s(&fileName, MAX_FILEPATH, argv[1], MAX_FILEPATH);
    ...
}
```

As you can see, the author is defining the MAX_FILEPATH as 255, but I cannot do the same because the input argument I will give may be larger than that.

I decided to do dynamic memory allocation with malloc, so I can have an auto-sized array (the exact argument's length) and also, to save me the 'memcpy_s' function:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "Windows.h"

#pragma warning (disable: 6011 6386 6387) // MSVC is giving me a headache.

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int length = strlen(argv[1]); // Yes, I only care for 1 input argument.
    char* path = malloc(length * sizeof(char));

    int i = 0;
    for (; i <= length; i++) {
        if (i < length) {
            path[i] = argv[1][i];
        }
        else {
            path[i] = '\0';
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

I know that the 'for cicle' is probably not the best option in terms of speed, but I am not worried about it, yet. Instead, I am worried because everything seems to be fine, but when I reach the second part of the code (which is the creation of the HANDLE), it is always returning error.

```
HANDLE file = CreateFileA(path, GENERIC_ALL, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

if (file == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    printf_s("Nope."); // Always throwing nopes.
}
```

Do you have an idea of what am I doing wrong? Maybe the way I am trying to mix up different data types or functions...?

Thank you very much, in advance.

By the way, if you have suggestions about my C coding style, or if something is not really 'C standard', please, let me know.

## IF SOMEONE IS HAVING THE SAME PROBLEM...

Try to run your program as Admin... it is all about file permissions.

Comment: Make that `char* path = malloc(length+1);` for the terminating null character.
`

Comment: What is wrong with just using `argv[1]`? E.g. `char *path= argv[1];`? Or just forget about `path` at all.

Comment: Anyway, following the proper `malloc` just do `strcpy`.

Comment: Also, `sizeof(char)` is always one by definition.  And if you're using `memcpy_s()` because MSVC said `memcpy()` was "deprecated", be aware you were effectively lied to.  `memcpy()` hasn't been and won't be deprecated by anyone - it's [standard C](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.24.2.1) and it's not going away.  MSVC pushes you to use the `*_s` functions that would be standard per Annex K of the C standard, but Microsoft's implementation is non-standard and non-portable.  See http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1967.htm#impementations

Comment: Thank you for your advices; I'll fix them and keep going :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless there is some other reason for it, there is no need to copy `argv[1]` you could just use it instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Windows.h> // use normal include guards

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2){ // if the argument is not there the program would have undefined behavior
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: <prog> <filename>\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    
    HANDLE file = CreateFileA(argv[1], GENERIC_ALL, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    //                        ^^^^^^^
    if (file == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        printf_s("Nope."); // Always throwing nopes.
    }
    //...
}
```

In any case you should check if `argv[1]` is really there otherwise your program will have undefined behavior.

Anyway, if you really want to do the copy there are better alternatives, here is one of them:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h> // maybe needed for strdup
#include <Windows.h> // use normal include guards


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    if(argc < 2){ // if the argument is not there the program would have undefined behavior
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: <prog> <filename>\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    // allocates memory for the new string and duplicates it
    char* path = _strdup(argv[1]); // MSVC can complain about POSIX strdup()
    //...
    // you'll need to free path
}
```

Using the correct size for the array you can still use one of the `memcpy` or  `strcpy` library functions or one of its variants:

```
int length = strlen(argv[1]) + 1; // account for null byte
char *path = malloc(length); // sizeof char is always 1 byte
memcpy_s(path, length, argv[1], length); // path is already pointer, removing &
```

Note that in your code, `filename`, when passed as argument, decays to a pointer to its first element, so you should also remove `&`.

Or simply use a pointer:

```
char *path = argv[1];
```

Though the pointer option would be basically the same as simply using `argv[1]` directly, as shown in the first code.

If there is another problem not related to the string, `GetLastError()` will help you pinpoint what it is.

Comment: I have followed both approaches (using argv[1] directly and the full memcpy function) but it is still throwing "nopes", like if it was unable to read the file (file == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE).. :(

Comment: @JulioVargas, all the 3 should work, try printing out `GetLastError()` to see what the exact error is, and post it here. You may have to use `LPTSTR argv[]` and `TCHAR` instead of `char` if you are using Unicode characters.

Comment: GetLastError() == 5, so it meant that it was all about permissions.. I ran the program as Admin and everything worked fine. Thank you for the suggestions!

Comment: @JulioVargas, indeed it is, glad you solved it, note that you can [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/684852) if you think it decisively helped you solved the issue.